# Visual Studio 2012: Unresolved external symbol _BluetoothFindFirstRadio

Tags: windows-8, linker, visual-studio-2012, bluetooth, lnk2019

I'm trying to use some Bluetooth functions ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362927(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) in a Win32 Console Application project. After including the relevant headers, I get linker errors like the following during compilation:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _BluetoothFindFirstRadio@8 referenced in function _wmain
```

I've been assuming that I have failed to link to the Windows 8 SDK. Opening the project properties, my targeted framework is .NET 4.0 which I cannot change and there are no references I can add either.

I may be entirely off-base. How do I resolve this compilation error?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're compiling native code (Win32), adding references won't work as they do in C#/.NET. What you need to do is;

- Select "Properties" on your project.
- Expand "Configuration Properties".
- Expand "Linker".
- Select "Input".
- Add "Bthprops.lib" to "Additional Dependencies".

Bthprops.lib is mentioned as needed in the [BluetoothFindFirstRadio documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362786(v=vs.85).aspx).

Compile, and all should be well.

Comment: Or, alternatively, `#pragma comment(lib, "bthprops.lib")` in your stdafx.cpp (or some other file)

Comment: @NikBougalis I've seen that syntax, but never quite researched/used it. Thanks for the clarification :)